# IT Networking: Tiny managed 2-port network switch?

Tags: networking, switch

Is there such a thing as a fully managed mini 2-port network switch?

I would like to move printers to a dedicated and isolated VLAN, but most of the printers don't have built-in VLAN support, and they are located in places where multiple walljacks are available so it may not be always plugged into a static assigned wall VLAN port correctly.

I would like to set the printers up with a tiny managed switch that will send them to the proper VLAN, and otherwise it just won't work if any of the cabling is mixed up by staff doing summer cleaning. The switch should have a way to detect the printer's MAC and refuse a connection if that MAC can't be found.

Answer (score 2):

Mikrotik has various devices, for example [mAP](https://mikrotik.com/product/RBmAP2nD) with suggested price $45. Wireless You can disable. You can power it via POE.